# How to open a files specified by sys.argv in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I am getting an error where it says:

> no such file or directory exists`

The file is in the same directory where I keep my code is.

Here is my code:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename=argv
txt=open(filename)
print(f"So the name of the file is {filename}.")
print(txt.read())
```

Output:on cmd

```
E:\python codes\ python file1.py  test.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File"file1.py", line 4, in <modeule>
     txt=open(filename)
FileNotFoundError:: [Erno 2]No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

Comment: How are you running this? You've not specified what `argv` is set to

Comment: Cannot reproduce...

Comment: Actually I am new to python, and I am practising it with Learn python 3 the hard way.This was the exercise for reading the file.

Comment: Please copy the error traceback  text into your question

Comment: Try  `print(argv)` to see what is in this variable.

Comment: Does the file actually exist, in the directory where you are running the script? Try `python file1.py file1.py` to read the script itself instead.

Comment: The *current directory* is not the directory that contains the source but the current directory where you are when you start the Python interpreter. What shows (after `import os`) `print(os.getcwd())`?

Comment: The file exists in the directory itself@Evert

Comment: If I print(argv) ,it is printing ['file1.py','test.py'] @buhtz

Comment: You say `argv` prints `test.py` as its second element in the comment above, yet your example uses `test.txt`. Let's say `test.txt` exist, but you run your script with `test.py` as argument, then, yes, the script will error. Please double check if you're not making a simple typo by mixing up extensions.

Comment: @Evert right, removed it